# How to display Data in View through LINQ?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I am NEW in MVC3 so bear with me here. I went through this link to start learning MVC3:
[ASP.NET MVC3 Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript)

I created everything alright. Now I want to go one step ahead with LINQ. In my UserModel class (as in this example) I created this code in another class inside this called User where there is implementation of Adding, Deleting, Editing.

```
 DataDataContext dt = new DataDataContext();
            var q = from a in dt.GetTable<Entity>()
                    select a;
```

> 'Data' is the DBMLconnection for LINQ. And Entity is the table.

Now how should I select selective columns in the table (Entity) to my view? Any answers or links will be appreciated! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should start with:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1

In your code. Pass first the entity to your linq.

Then after that in your Controller right click return view(q) and then click add view and select details.

Regards